# stop date selection in jquery date picker

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I have following code

```
$(this).datepicker({ minDate: 0,
                onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
                    var sdate = $(this).val();

                    var cnt = $(".txtdate[value='" + sdate + "']").length;
                   if (cnt == '0')
                        return true;
                    else {
                        alert('You have planned for this date');
                        return false;
                    }
                }

            });
```

i want to stop user to select duplicate date , i am able to do compare and everything, i am stuck at one place,

I am returning false to not select the date

but still its selecting date

what i am doing wrong in code

Please help

Thanks

Comment: check format of sdate in your script with value entered by user. To get date I use $("#datepicker_id").datepicker("getDate").

Comment: i am able to validate the date, with if else, and if else working but its selecting date in both condition

Comment: Try to use [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/).

Comment: You can try to reset it with $.datepicker._clearDate(this) Or other variant destroy .datepicker("destroy") and recreate it.

Comment: @AndreiV , its not working :-(

Comment: @mvb13 , not working, its selecting date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(this).datepicker({ minDate: 0,
                onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
                    var sdate = $(this).val();

                    var cnt = $(".txtdate[value='" + sdate + "']").length;
                   if (cnt == '0')
                        return true;
                    else {
                        alert('You have planned for this date');
                          $(this).val(' ')
                        return false;
                    }
                }

            });
```